# VNC via VPN in a VM

Tags: vpn, virtualization

Yea you read that correctly...

What I want to achieve is the following: Have a lightweight VM running which VPNs into my work network... And then run a VNC session on my local machine that tunnels through that VM's VPN connection into my work machine.

The reason I want to do this is because my work network doesn't allow browsing websites from outside machines, so when I VPN in I have to browse the sites that I want via my VNC session, or even worse on a tablet, which isn't optimal for my use-case.

I'm running 14:04 ubuntu and already run several VMs locally for other VPNs, but the closest that I come to accessing them from my local network is via a webbrowser that they are running locally.

So:
Is this scenario possible?
How complicated is it going to be?

Thanks

---- edit ----

how is this for an answer, for a vncserver running on *WORK_MACHINE:XXXX*

```
ssh -f VM_SERVER -L YYYY:WORK_MACHINE:XXXX -N
```

and then

```
vncviewer localhost:YYYY
```

Comment: Why are you doing the VPN in a virtual machine?

Comment: I was trying to keep it contained.

Comment: The `-L` should not have `username@` in it because that's not something SSH knows about. But if you're suggesting that as an answer, why don't you accept mine which says the same thing?

Comment: Yours doesn't say the same thing: I still had to piece together information from other sources to get the full picture. Perhaps you can edit your post to be explicit with the information and I'll accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, while the VM is connected to the VPN, you can still access it from the host machine over the network, then you could use SSH tunneling.

Have the host connect via ssh to the client and forward the host's port `XXXX` to `HostABC.MyCompanyLAN.com:YYYY`. Then, when you VNC to `localhost:XXXX`, it will go through to the VM and then get routed through its VPN to `HostABC`.

You could also just VNC from within the VM.

Or you could connect to the VPN from the host and skip the VM entirely.

Comment: I was trying to keep the VNC out of the VM - as it is another layer to steal keystrokes.

Comment: if I've got MachineA on the VPN network (that I'm trying to vnc into), the VM and Client machine that i"m sitting at. Who is getting the port forwarded?